# db.First() not using primary key name

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am writing some sample code to understand `gorm` but appear to be having an issue with setting up the `primary_key` value. As a result, the resulting SQL query is broken.

Please see the sample code:
package main

```golang
import (
        "os"
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
        "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Post struct {
        id              int             `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key:id"`
        url             string          `gorm:"url"`
        content         string          `gorm:"content"`
        created_at      time.Time       `gorm:"created_at"`
        normalized      string          `gorm:"normalized"`
        account_id      int             `gorm:"account_id"`
        posthash        []byte          `gorm:"posthash"`
        received_at     time.Time       `gorm:"received_at"`
}

func main() {
        dsn := "user=postgres dbname=localtest"
        db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("An error occurred", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        db.AutoMigrate(&Post{})
        var post Post
        db.First(&post, 1)
        fmt.Println(post)
}
```

When I run this code, I receive the following error:

```
$ go run gorm_test.go

2020/12/01 00:34:06 /home/farhan/gorm_test.go:32 ERROR: syntax error at or near "=" (SQLSTATE 42601)
[0.128ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "posts" WHERE "posts". = 1 ORDER BY "posts". LIMIT 1
{0   {0 0 <nil>}  0 [] {0 0 <nil>}}
```

The nature of this error suggests to me that the `primary_key` value is not set. I tried `primaryKey` and `primarykey`, but none appeared to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Your structure declaration is bad; you need to export fields so gorm can use them https://gorm.io/docs/models.html

Answer (score 3):

> @Shubham Srivastava - Your structure declaration is bad; you need to export fields so gorm can use them [Declaring Models](http://gorm.io/docs/models.html)

❗️Use **exported** `ID` field

In Go, when a field name starts with a lowercase letter that means the field is private (called unexported in Go parlance). Gorm, being a third party package, cannot see inside your struct to know there is an `id` field, or any other unexported field for that matter.

The solution is to make sure all the fields that need to come from the DB are exported:

```
type Post struct {
  ID uint `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
  ...
}
```